# GraphQL only returning one item from array instead of all items

Tags: graphql

I have a GraphQL query which is meant to return a full array list containing 9 items, but it's only returning 1 item. This is an Array of Objects.

If I console log `data.dataJson` it returns the first Object in the array as an Object, not Array...

I'm new to using GraphQL so any pointers would be appreciated!

Query

```
export const ProjectsQuery = graphql`
    query IndexQuery {
        dataJson {
            title
            img 
            type
            category
            url
        }
    }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was down to having an unnamed array in the JSON. Changing to the following fixed the issue:

```
{
  "projects": [
    {
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```